# What is space complexity for breadth-first search on a binary tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree, time-complexity, breadth-first-search, space-complexity

Here is my Java solution for printing a binary tree level by level with breadth first search(it works!!)

```
public void printByLevel() {
    System.out.print("Elements By Level:");
    if(overallRoot!= null) {
        Queue<IntTreeNode> bfs = new LinkedList<IntTreeNode>();
        bfs.add(overallRoot);
        while(!bfs.isEmpty()) {
            IntTreeNode root = bfs.remove();
            System.out.print(" " + root.data);
            if(root.left!=null) 
                bfs.add(root.left);
            if(root.right!=null)
                bfs.add(root.right);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

I know with my breadth-first search algorithm, I will visit all the nodes in the tree so the time complexity of the algorithm will be *O(n)*.

I am having trouble with analyzing the space complexity of my solution though. I learned from  [Space Complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29225659/is-the-space-complexity-of-this-subset-algorithm-actually-on) that when analyzing space complexity, you have to take into account the space you allocate from the heap and the stack

Here, I am not making any recursive calls so the space complexity will just be the space I allocated for the queue for breadth-first-search. I read from here  [BFS Complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261112/time-and-space-complexities-of-breadth-first-search)  that the space complexity of breadth first search is O(V) where V is the number of vertices.

Does that same  space complexity apply to my tree variation? I have yet to produce a test case in which the BFS queue will hold all the nodes in the tree. Even when the binary tree  degenerates to a linked list like in the following pictorial that I got from  [BST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28772080/why-is-add-in-unbalanced-binary-search-tree-on), where normal operations on a tree take O(n) time and O(n) space, the BFS queue will hold at most 1 element.

```
    1
     \
      2
       \
        3
         \
          4
           \
            5
             \
              ...`
```

Can anyone give me a test case in which the BFS queue will hold all the nodes in tree, proving that the space complexity is *O(n)*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the "full" or "perfect" binary tree:

```
     .
   / .
  0  .
 / \ .
0    .
 \ / .
  0  .
   \ .
     .
```

At the last iteration, the queue will hold roughly half of the nodes in the tree, so the complexity is `O(n/2)`, which is the same as `O(n)`.